# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error when throwing error

Tags: node.js, async-await

My code consist of route, global error handler and one validation function.
First version of the code was totally synchronous and everything worked fine. Now I am trying to make it asyc so the validation function looks like this:

```
const validateGenres = async (genres) => {
    const fromDB = await genre.find(); // code here is fine, it always find genres
    const validationArr = genres.reduce((acc, e) => {
        ...code
    }, [])

    if (validationArr.length !== 0) {
        throw new ValidationError(`Missing genres ${validationArr}`); //this error causes UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
    }

    return genres;
}
```

To catch all errors I have created global error handler:

```
async function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  logger.log({ message: err, level: 'error' });
  if (err instanceof CustomError) {
    return res.status(err.statusCode).send({ errors: err.serializeErrors() });
  }

  res.status(400).send({
    errors: [{ message: 'Something went wrong' }]
  });
```

}

The problem is that now whenever new ValidationError is thrown it won't go and execute errorHandler but instead of it it will throw:

```
(node:11253) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
    at validateGenres (/home/mat/Projects/-task-v3/-task-v3/src/middlewares/schema-validator.js:16:15)
    at async /home/mat/Projects/-task-v3/-task-v3/src/routes/findAll.js:19:28
```

The findAll is basically router endpoint and looks like:

```
router.get('/api/movies/findAll/:runtime?/:genres?', async (req, res) => {
    movies = await movie.find(params);  
    res.status(200).json(movies)
})
```

What is more, to register global error handler Ive done this:

```
const app = express();
app.use(json());

app.use(findAllRouter);
app.use(createRouter);

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));

app.all('*', async (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).json({ "errors": [ { "message": "No such endpoint" } ] })
});

app.use(errorHandler);


const start = () => app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`) });

module.exports = { start }
```

Comment: How/where do you call `validateGenres`? It should be in a `try .. catch` block. And when it throws you should pass the error using `next(err)`

Comment: Thank you, for this hint. It works like charm now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with using `async` function as middleware callback in express.
Express won't catch your uncaught exceptions in `async` callback function and you will get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

If you want `async` callback, you can do the following:

```
// Declare on this wrapper function
function callbackWrap(fn) {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);
    };
}

// And use it in your code
router.get('/api/movies/findAll/:runtime?/:genres?', callbackWrap(async (req, res) => {
    movies = await movie.find(params);  
    res.status(200).json(movies)
}))
```

Do it for your `errorHandler` too (though if the `async` is not required, it will be better to remove it)